# Why am I getting System.ArgumentException in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me out? I'm trying to draw an image and I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

There are the functions:

```
Dim x, y, xlatime, ylungime As Integer
Dim myImage As Image
Dim folder As String

Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender1 As Object, er As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim r As New Rectangle(x, y, xlatime, ylungime)
    er.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, r)
End Sub

Private Function deseneaza(ByVal poza As String, ByRef x_perm As Integer, ByRef y_perm As Integer, ByRef lungime As Integer, ByRef latime As Integer)
    myImage = Image.FromFile(poza)
    x = x_perm
    y = y_perm
    xlatime = latime
    ylungime = lungime
    Refresh()
    Return Nothing
End Function

 Private Sub joaca_buton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles joaca_buton.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    nor.Hide()
    nor_mic.Hide()
    logo.Hide()
    exit_buton.Hide()
    joaca_buton.Hide()
    continua_buton.Hide()
    optiuni_buton.Hide()
    BackgroundImage.Dispose()
    deseneaza(folder + "\incarcare1.png", 0, 0, 729, 1008)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the image loaded? Did you debug your work?

Comment: The paint event fires many times unless you tell it you are controlling that - and I see no code for that. So by the time you open the form the paint event is firing.

Comment: If your function doesn't return anything, it should be a sub. Please post a more complete code including declarations.

Comment: Ok, so what can i do to controll the paint event's fires ?

Comment: I changed that function in a sub, but still nothing.

Comment: Please read your answer below! The function to a sub had nothing to do with your error.

Comment: I read the answer, but that didn't fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picturebox's paint event will be called before the button was clicked. In that case, `MyImage` would be `Nothing`, thus causing the exception when you try to paint it. Change the paint event to include a check:

```
Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender1 As Object, er As PaintEventArgs)
    If myImage IsNot Nothing Then    
        Dim r As New Rectangle(x, y, xlatime, ylungime)
        er.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, r)
    End If
End Sub
```

And to force a redraw, add `Picturebox1.Invalidate()` to the end of `Sub joaca_buton_Click`.

```
Private Sub joaca_buton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles joaca_buton.Click
    'The rest of the sub here
    deseneaza(folder + "\incarcare1.png", 0, 0, 729, 1008)
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. I dont have an PictureBox1, so how can force a redraw without the "PictureBox1.Invalidate()" ?

Comment: @CătălinMuntean Since you have a `PictureBox1_Paint` in the code you posted, I assumed that that is what the control is called. Call `Invalidate` for the control you are drawing the image to. If the exception still occurs, post more info about the exact location in your code that causes it.

Comment: I called Invalidate , but still nothing. I wanted to draw an image as big as the form size. The "Refresh()" causes it, but i found another solution for doing what i want. Thank you for trying to help me out , i really  appreciate that.

Comment: `Refresh()` belongs to the form for it's paint event.